# Procedure or Function expects parameter error which was not supplied

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, stored-procedures

I'm using the database created via ASP.NET Configuration Manager, After logging in, I have a page that show the user's client in a Gridview, but I only want the user to see their respective clients only.

// the code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        String strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BA_2014ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = "getClients";
        cmd.Connection = con;

            con.Open();
            gvClients.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            gvClients.DataBind();

            con.Close();
            con.Dispose();

    }
```

// the stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.getClients
@UserId uniqueidentifier
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT ClientId, UserId, ClientName, EmailAddress, PhoneNumber, ServicesNum FROM  Client_tb WHERE @UserId = UserId  

END
```

...when I remove the where clause, the gridview shows all the clients. However when the where clause is in place, I get the error: "Procedure or Function 'getClients' expects parameter '@UserId', which was not supplied." Could I get some help please?

Comment: If my answer (below) solved your problem, please mark it as "accepted answer" (with the green V) and you also gain 2 reputations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should supply the UserId to your Stored Procedure from your C# code like this:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserId", SqlDbType.bytes).Value = txtUserId.Text;
```

Im not sure about the `SqlDbType.bytes` because i'm not near Visual Studio at the moment but it should be something like that.

Comment: Thanks, problem resolved, apologies for the late reply, just returning from a mini-vacation. Thanks again!